# How to remove the numbers at the beginning of each line in python?

Tags: python

I have a block of code that has to manipulate a .txt file. I'm trying to remove the first three numbers and '.', in order to use the code without having to manually deleting each number.

recieving error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

I've tried replacing the first number of characters in the list, replacing the specified numbers and casting them to strings before doing so, but I keep recieving the same error.

.txt document to modify:

```
  1. """Birthday Paradox Simulation, by Al Sweigart al@inventwithpython.com
  2. Explore the surprising probabilities of the "Birthday Paradox".
  3. More info at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem
  4. This code is available at https://nostarch.com/big-book-small-python-programming
  5. Tags: short, math, simulation"""
  6. 
  7. import datetime, random
  8. 
  9. 
 10. def getBirthdays(numberOfBirthdays):
 11.     """Returns a list of number random date objects for birthdays."""
 12.     birthdays = []
 13.     for i in range(numberOfBirthdays):
 14.         # The year is unimportant for our simulation, as long as all
 15.         # birthdays have the same year.
 16.         startOfYear = datetime.date(2001, 1, 1)
 17. 
 18.         # Get a random day into the year:
 19.         randomNumberOfDays = datetime.timedelta(random.randint(0, 364))
 20.         birthday = startOfYear + randomNumberOfDays
 21.         birthdays.append(birthday)
 22.     return birthdays
 23. 
 24. 
 25. def getMatch(birthdays):
 26.     """Returns the date object of a birthday that occurs more than once
 27.     in the birthdays list."""
 28.     if len(birthdays) == len(set(birthdays)):
 29.         return None  # All birthdays are unique, so return None.
 30. 
 31.     # Compare each birthday to every other birthday:
 32.     for a, birthdayA in enumerate(birthdays):
 33.         for b, birthdayB in enumerate(birthdays[a + 1 :]):
 34.             if birthdayA == birthdayB:
 35.                 return birthdayA  # Return the matching birthday.
 36. 
 37. 
 38. # Display the intro:
 39. print('''Birthday Paradox, by Al Sweigart al@inventwithpython.com
 40. 
 41. The birthday paradox shows us that in a group of N people, the odds
 42. that two of them have matching birthdays is surprisingly large.
 43. This program does a Monte Carlo simulation (that is, repeated random
 44. simulations) to explore this concept.
 45. 
 46. (It's not actually a paradox, it's just a surprising result.)
 47. ''')
 48. 
 49. # Set up a tuple of month names in order:
 50. MONTHS = ('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
 51.           'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec')
 52. 
 53. while True:  # Keep asking until the user enters a valid amount.
 54.     print('How many birthdays shall I generate? (Max 100)')
 55.     response = input('> ')
 56.     if response.isdecimal() and (0 < int(response) <= 100):
 57.         numBDays = int(response)
 58.         break  # User has entered a valid amount.
 59. print()
 60. 
 61. # Generate and display the birthdays:
 62. print('Here are', numBDays, 'birthdays:')
 63. birthdays = getBirthdays(numBDays)
 64. for i, birthday in enumerate(birthdays):
 65.     if i != 0:
 66.         # Display a comma for each birthday after the first birthday.
 67.         print(', ', end='')
 68.     monthName = MONTHS[birthday.month - 1]
 69.     dateText = '{} {}'.format(monthName, birthday.day)
 70.     print(dateText, end='')
 71. print()
 72. print()
 73. 
 74. # Determine if there are two birthdays that match.
 75. match = getMatch(birthdays)
 76. 
 77. # Display the results:
 78. print('In this simulation, ', end='')
 79. if match != None:
 80.     monthName = MONTHS[match.month - 1]
 81.     dateText = '{} {}'.format(monthName, match.day)
 82.     print('multiple people have a birthday on', dateText)
 83. else:
 84.     print('there are no matching birthdays.')
 85. print()
 86. 
 87. # Run through 100,000 simulations:
 88. print('Generating', numBDays, 'random birthdays 100,000 times...')
 89. input('Press Enter to begin...')
 90. 
 91. print('Let\'s run another 100,000 simulations.')
 92. simMatch = 0  # How many simulations had matching birthdays in them.
 93. for i in range(100000):
 94.     # Report on the progress every 10,000 simulations:
 95.     if i % 10000 == 0:
 96.         print(i, 'simulations run...')
 97.     birthdays = getBirthdays(numBDays)
 98.     if getMatch(birthdays) != None:
 99.         simMatch = simMatch + 1
100. print('100,000 simulations run.')
101. 
102. # Display simulation results:
103. probability = round(simMatch / 100000 * 100, 2)
104. print('Out of 100,000 simulations of', numBDays, 'people, there was a')
105. print('matching birthday in that group', simMatch, 'times. This means')
106. print('that', numBDays, 'people have a', probability, '% chance of')
107. print('having a matching birthday in their group.')
108. print('That\'s probably more than you would think!')
```

```
#program number remover

with open("programtext.txt") as f:
    lines= f.readlines()
#    print(lines)
    
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        print(lines)
        lines.replace(i,'.')
```

Comment: It looks like you meant to write `print(i)` and `i.replace`. That doesn't solve the problem though.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and see [ask] for tips like making a [mre]. I mention it cause that's a lot more data than you need to demonstrate the problem here. Just a few lines would have worked fine.

Comment: So you never have a file with more than 999 lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the part to be removed is of fixed-length, you can simply use slicing:

```py
with open("text.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line[5:], end='')
```

Output:

```
"""Birthday Paradox Simulation, by Al Sweigart al@inventwithpython.com
Explore the surprising probabilities of the "Birthday Paradox".
More info at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem
This code is available at https://nostarch.com/big-book-small-python-programming
Tags: short, math, simulation"""

import datetime, random


def getBirthdays(numberOfBirthdays):

...
```

Comment: why does removing ```end=''``` stop the program from adding print() to the beginning of each line?

Comment: When you iterate over `f` (or `f.readlines()`), each `line` already has `'\n'`. A plain `print` without `end` parameter adds `'\n'` by default. So `print(line)` actually will have two line breaks. `end=''` suppresses this.

Answer (score 1):

Just take the line and split it on the first `.`. This returns a list of 2 elements. The number to the left, and the rest of the content. So you grab the second element.

```
for line in lines:
    new_line = line.split('. ', 1)[1]
    print(new_line)
```

Comment: @Kelly Yeah, and an extra newline at each line's end

Comment: easy fix. just add the space to the split